# UserControl Dock/Anchor not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here's a complete simple case:

1. I created a **UserControl**. And added a **Button** on it **Anchor**ed top-right.
2. I **Dock.Fill**ed the **UserControl** in **Form1**.

The **Button** is not in the correct place when executing (though it is in the Designer).

## Screenshots:

`UserControl` Designer:

[image]

`Form` Designer:

[image]

Executing:

[image]

Executing, resized. As you can see, that doesn't help:

[image]

I tried changing my computer's text size from 125% to 100% but that didn't help either. Windows 10, VS 2017, .Net 4.7.1. I also tried setting the UserControl's Dock in its `Load` and `ParentChanged` event handlers, and its constructor. No change.

So how do I get the button to stay anchored?

**EDIT** (it seems to be somehow related to text size being different than 100%)

After a lot of fiddling I see now that after I change to 100% size text (In the Settings app under System-Display. Including logging off and on), clean and rebuild the solution, and then change back to 125% it works for some time. I can't find the exact limit for that.

Comment: You must have some resizing code in the UC or form that's overriding it. Based off of your writeup, it should work. Check events in the UC and form for anything that's setting width (especially the button width). https://vimeo.com/241579366

Comment: @Aaron I appreciate you're testing this! And I can see that your test works fine. unfortunately, my code is exactly as I wrote. I started with a clean Winforms template, and added _only_ what I wrote. _No other code at all!_. Are you running the same environment as I? (Win10 Fall Creators Update, VS2017, The app is .net 4.7.1)

Comment: I did it on 4.6.1 on Win10 Pro. I don't even have 4.7 installed right now. Give me a few, I probably need to install it anyway.

Comment: @Aaron No need. I started playing with everything again, since I saw you're example working, and though it already had Dock as Fill - I changed it to None and made it again Fill, and now it seems to work. (I had already tried Rebuilding before that and that didn't help). I'm just testing that this was actually the problem, a little VS bug...

Comment: ...And it's not working again....

Comment: is your user control solely containing a button? if this is the case, you can crop out the empty area, make the user control size to be same size as the button. fill your button to the user control instead of making it docking to the top-right.

Comment: @JoeWu This is just a simplified example. The real application is more complicated. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ispiro, could you please try to disable DPI awareness on your VisualStudio process and see if it helps. Here is a blog post that specifies the registry key to set:
https://code4ward.net/2016/11/29/visual-studio-winforms-designer-on-highdpi/

Comment: This is an option I hadn't considered - that the trouble lies with the VS Designer. Thanks. I would guess this is the answer.

Comment: This works, but the blured fonts in Visual Studio are not so nice ...
Are there news about the topic especially with Framework 4.7.1?